# IIS7: How to import public key and private key as two seperate files?

Tags: iis, ssl

We have a client who is directing their traffic to our web servers and needs us to use their wildcard SSL certificate. They gave it to me in two pieces though, one is the public key (*.cer) and another file containing the private key (*.key). I can't figure out how to get these two to come together in IIS so I can bind it to a site. Assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll just need to convert the separate certificate files to a .pfx to import it into IIS: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

Comment: Isn't it a bit of a security risk to send your certificate with private key to a third party site. You have no control over when they then do with that information. Do you trust them?

Comment: @johnstaveley It absolutely is. I've used this tool once or twice in the past when importing development environment certificates and I wasn't particularly concerned about exposing them. However, I would definitely avoid using this (or any!) site to convert your certificates when you can easily do so with a simple command in `openssl`, which will most likely be installed on your computer.

Answer (score 36):

You may need to use [OpenSSL](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) to convert the file formats to PFX and then use the Certificates MMC snap-in to import them into the local computer's personal store.

The OpenSSL command is something like this -

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

Comment: What is certificate.crt and CACert.crt in this case ?

Comment: "-inkey privateKey.key" is your private key. "-in certificate.crt" is your certificate. "-certfile CACert.crt" can be used to include any intermediate certificates (optional)  

Reference "File Creation Options"  @ https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/openssl-pkcs12.html

Answer (score 2):

You could ask your client if the certificate could be exported as .pfx file. You can easily import the pfx file using IIS Manager.

Here is a link to a tutorial: [PFX Export/Import Explained - How to Import and Export your SSL Certificate in IIS 7](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the certificate into the certificate store on your computer.  The certificate store is an MMC snap-in.